# Finding the limit of $\lim_{ x\rightarrow 3^-} ((\sqrt{3x+7}-4)/(\sqrt{3-x}))$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

How do I evaluate $\lim\limits_{ x\rightarrow 3^-}\dfrac{\sqrt{3x+7}-4}{\sqrt{3-x}}$? 
Can someone explain the steps by steps solution to this problem?

Comment: Multiply top and bottom by $\sqrt{3x+7}+4$. After a short while you should conclude that the limit is $0$. Or use L'Hospital's Rule.

Answer (score 2):

Let $t=3-x$ then the limit becomes
$$\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\sqrt{16-3t}-4}{\sqrt t}=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{-3t}{\sqrt t(\sqrt{16-3t}+4)}=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{-3\sqrt t}{\sqrt{16-3t}+4}=0$$

Comment: Nice approach, Sami.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Since $$\lim_{x\to 3}\frac{\sqrt{3x+7}-4}{\sqrt{3-x}}$$ gives $0/0$ (indeterminate form), you can use L'Hopitals Rule

Answer (score 0):

If I read your text correctly, you are trying to solve:
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 3} {{\sqrt{3x+7}-4}\over {\sqrt{3-x}}}
$$

To solve this, I would substitute $x = 3 + {16\delta \over 3}$, and simplify.

Then I would use the Taylor expansion of square-root: $\sqrt{1+\delta} = 1 + {1\over 2} \delta + ...$  As $\delta$ approaches zero, higher order terms can be ignored.